# Best design for tracking Order changes

Tags: sql-server, database, logging, database-design, audit

Need to track following changes on order;

- who created the order and when
- who added/updated/deleted an item with qty and when

I have this in mind but not sure if its any good plus not sure about naming convention

**LogEventType**

- ID
- Type (i.e. UPDATE, DELETE, ADD)

**OrderLog**

- LogID
- EventType (FK_LogOperation_ID)
- OrderID
- Itemnum
- Qty
- UserName

Comment: do you already have an Order table?, what kind of table is it?  type1 or type2(keep history)?

Comment: Yes there is order header and detail table.

Comment: do you keep history?

Comment: no, it is not required.

Comment: You could use a trigger (GASP) and log data into a new table trackign that information. Or enabled CDC. Or use extended events

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do without going deep in to changing your existing setup and least amount of work.  I welcome criticism.

I assume that when someone removes/adds an item, the order header and detail tables are immediately updated with the new information (type 1 - in place update)

To that end,
I would change ORDERLOG to ORDERHISTORY.  In it, I would have The current order and any changes to it.  it would be an append.  A new order will be a new record.  A update is another new record, etc.

Copy all the fields in ORDER_HEADER and ORDER_HISTORY to ORDERHISTORY.  Then add columns for change detection, is current, and change dates.   There's more to it, but this will work for now.  It is up to you, but you can make the columns like:

```
CHANGE_TYPE CHAR(1) -- 'A' to add, 'C' to change, 'D' to delete.
IS_CURRENT INT -- 1 is latest record, 0 is not
EFFECTIVE_DATE  DATETIME -- GETEDATE() when record is inserted
```

when something occurs, insert a record into ORDERHISTORY.  follow the business rules above, and you will be able to see the full history of the order from initial to final.

You can set a trigger on the ORDER_HEADER table to insert the record whenever that table is effected in any way.

of note, this creates table creep, so make sure you archive or delete when no longer needed often.